# Is there a way to prevent browsers from upscaling images?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my webpage, I use images that are 720px by 480px. If I look at them in Firefox or IE (latest version) however they look scaled up, they are considerably larger on the screen than their original version in Lightroom. If I look at the dimensions of the picture on the web though, it says that it is 720x480. If I want the files to be as big as they should be, then I have to set the width-property to 600px, which I think is odd..
The webpage uses Bootstrap 3.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

There may be styles being applied by Bootstrap or something else, which are causing the issue.  If you look in the inspector of your browser, it will show you all of the rules that apply to a given element.  Also, your browser may be zoomed.  The shortcut to reset it to default is usually Ctrl-0, though there is also usually also an option listed in the menus.

Comment: Yeah. Make sure Bootstrap isn't making the image responsive and scaling it